# Linha Mediana Chart JS Line

Tags: chartjs

Tenho um gráfico como a imagem abaixo em ChartJs:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível traçar uma linha reta que demonstre a média dos valores como na imagem abaixo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código Gráfico:

```
$(function () {
    new Chart(document.getElementById("graficoOcupacao").getContext("2d"), getChartJs('line'));
});

function getChartJs(type) {

    var config = null;

    if (type === 'line') {
        config = {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07","08","09","10","11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17","18","19","20","21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27","28","29","30"],
                datasets: [{
                    data: dadosGraficoValores,
                    borderColor: 'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.75)',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.3)',
                    pointBorderColor: 'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0)',
                    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.9)',
                    pointBorderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                legend: false,
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Dia'
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Ocupação (%)'
                        }
                    }]
                },
                title:{
                    display: true,
                    text:'NOVEMBRO/2017'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return config;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adiocione o Chart.Annotation.js no seu projeto e faça:

link https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation

```
annotation: {
    annotations: [{
        type: 'line',
        mode: 'horizontal',
        scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
        value: '25',
        borderColor: 'red',
        borderWidth: 2
    }]
}
```

nas `options` do grafico

Comment: Eu fico com o mesmo gráfico, porém, tenho que carregar este plugin? em que local eu colocaria este trecho de código?

Comment: continua tudo igual, voce só vai carregar mais um arquivo js, que seria o "anotation" e inserir esse trecho de código dentro de "options"

Comment: Tentei, até apareceu uma linha vermelha, porém, bem bem na parte inferior, conforme imagem: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/anotation-jpg

Comment: voce precisa editar o valor dela

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente